# Can you help me identify this italic, serif font?

Tags: font-identification, serif

Can you help me identify this font [image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's [Classical Garamond Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/classical-garamond/italic/):

[image: Classical Garamond Italic from MyFonts]

Points of interest are the asymmetric bowl of **q** together with its top-right serif, the tails of **u** together with the slant at the top of its vertical, the terminals of **s**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's [Bembo Book Italic](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/bembo-book/std-italic/)

[image]

For future reference, you can search on [Myfonts](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) yourself by uploading an image of the font.

Comment: what about "t"?

Comment: @Ilan I'm good thanks, I've drank ;) but now you mention it, it does look a little different

Comment: And *q* has a top-right serif in the question; and *R* has a serif on its diagonal. Bembo [doesn't](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/bembo-book/std-italic/glyphs.html). It is very similar, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think its [Octava Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/octava/pt-octava-italic/), by what MyFonts says.

[image]